# how to open Windows form application in "CLION"?

Tags: c++, clion

I am using windows 7 and working in clion 2016 . I am making a game in which I need to open a new window. I heard that it is impossible to open a window in c++ but you can open one using windows form application. I have made many projects in c but I am a beginer in windows form application. I do not know how to open a new window in it. Can somebody please help me